# ASP.NET Core MVC: 'format of the initialization string' error when scaffolding from migrated SQL Server database in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. ASp.net core Mvc

it migrates form visual studo to Sql sever but it don't work when scaffolding from database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpUTE.png)